# Install Kali Linux without GRUB?

Tags: windows-10, ssd, multi-boot, gparted, kali-linux

Is it possible, and is it actually best to just use my onboard UEFI to boot Kali Linux instead of using GRUB if Kali Linux is sharing the same drive as my Windows 10 OS?

I installed GRUB on my first attempt to install Kali Linux alongside Windows 10. GRUB never loaded, and when I used the original UEFI firmware to boot Kali Linux instead, I got GRUB and then accessed Kali Linux that way. It worked the first time I logged on, but then my login screen froze the second time I tried booting Kali.

And then, as soon as I restarted Windows 10 for an update, it wouldn't completely start. I ended up having to run back to a recent system image I made of Windows 10 (thank goodness I took all of these precautions).

I want to use Kali Linux for penetration testing of computers on my network. I don't think VirtualBox will help me accomplish this the way I need to. Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: Why don't you install Kali on an external drive, and boot from that? that's how it's typically meant to be used

Answer (score 0):

Well Virtual Box is by far the easiest and safest way to get started in pen testing, is like having a computer inside your computer so the difference wont be as big as long as you are not trying to do some heavy stuff.

But if you are sure that not for you can instead try to use the LILO instead of GRUB as that sometimes works as an alternative for some users. When you booted from the original UEFI tends to mess with eveything( personal experience ) the way I got around it was by using LILO instead of GRUB